# "Prediction" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm trying to create a new challenge type called [prediction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction). This is a very specific challenge that involves creating functions that try to match a given functions, but under memory constraints that make it impossible to just compute the value.

This is based on a question I made [back in 2014](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24571/print-a-specific-value-in-this-generated-binary-matrix?rq=1) (when people voted to just keep it as a code challenge), but my recent [Wythoff matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95604/print-a-specific-value-in-the-wythoff-matrix-modulo-2) question made me think about creating it again.

What do you think of this tag? Is it a good idea? Could it be something else? (I've already created a [binary-prediction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-prediction) tag, and there are a few problems [in the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10303/7110) that I'd create as examples of that particular variant of a [prediction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction) problem.)

Comment: So would this (in the vein of the wythoff question) be generating a heuristic function for a test battery? Or is that only one of a larger set of possible uses for the tag?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk That would be the intended gist of questions for that tag, yes.

Comment: I could also use "heuristic" + "test-battery", but the tag "heuristic" doesn't exist either.

Comment: Isn't [tag:test-battery] already used for challenges where you can't get all test cases right but are scored by how many you get right?

Comment: @MartinEnder [tag:test-battery] is more generally about optimization. Most of the problems there are about minimizing a particular objective value with respect to a given input, and do require all solutions to be correct.

Comment: Oh never mind, it seems like there's the [tag:classification] tag for this already.

Comment: [Like this?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69584/predict-whether-a-message-will-be-starred-or-not-in-50-bytes)

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes, exactly like that one.